# How to set permission for an external hard drive formatted in Hfs+?

Tags: permission

i've formatted an external hard drive in HFS+ using Ubuntu, and i've copied into 600 gb of data's.
Now, i've connected it to a Mac OsX Lion and shared it to a lan with 4 mac's.
The problem is that users can't create, copy or change any files! 
So i need (i think) to change all permission and owner of the hard drive files: but how ? 
The problem is that i try to change it (chmod, chown etc) but no change's is possible.
All files and folder remain as admin:staff !

How to do ?

Thank you!